# Why I can't reach the empty clause?

Tags: logic

Given the formula $(A\vee(B\to C))\to((A\vee B)\to(A\vee C))$, I need to prove that is a tautology using resolution. Firstly, I negated it and got to $(A\vee(\neg B\vee C))\wedge((A\vee B)\wedge(\neg A\wedge\neg C))$. Now I got the set of clauses $S = \{A,\neg B\vee C,A\vee B,\neg A\wedge\neg C\}$, but I can't get to the empty clause. What might have gone wrong? (I am sure it's tautology yes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close! You got the conversion to CNF ok, but you made a couple of mistakes converting that to clauses:

First: $A \lor (\neg B \lor C)$ is just $A \lor \neg B \lor C$, and that gives you the clause $\{ A, \neg B, C \}$

Second, $\neg A \land \neg C$ is not a clause by itself, but is two clauses: $\{ \neg A \}$ and $\{ \neg C \}$

I think that you are almost too careful in trying to keep all $\land$ and $\lor$ operators as binary operators ... but in this context, you really want to work with generalized conjunctions and disjunctions that can take any number of terms. So feel free to drop some parentheses!

In your case, we get a generalized conjunction with four conjuncts, where the first conjunct is a disjunction of three terms, and where the last two conjuncts are just a single term:  $(A \lor \neg B \lor C) \land (A \lor B) \land \neg A \land \neg C$

So now the statement is in CNF, and the nice thing is that that CNF directly translates into the clause set $\{ \{ A, \neg B, C \}, \{A \lor B\}, \{ \neg A \}, \{  \neg C\} \}$

Comment: I see.. Are there some rules for that? Then you'd get the empty clause just with A and ¬A right?

Comment: @KillHorizon23 'rules' is a big word ... once it is in CNF you just need to turn every conjunct into a clause ... and that clause is simply the set of all disjuncts in that conjunction.  So in your case, you have $(A \lor \neg B \lor C) \land (A \lor B) \land \neg A \land \neg C$ as the CNF, which directly translates into the clause set $\{ \{ A, \neg B, C \}, \{A \lor B\}, \{ \neg A \}, \{  \neg C\} \}$

Comment: @KillHorizon23 And yes, if you can get to $\{ A \}$ and $\{ \neg A \}$, then you can resolve those to the empty clause $\{ \}$

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense